# ConEmu: Open a new shell of the same configuration with a GuiMacro

Tags: conemu

How can I open up a new ConEmu shell of the same configuration?

For example, currently I open a new git bash shell with this GuiMacro:

`Shell("new_console", "{Bash::Git bash}", "", "%CD%")`

How can I make this more generic? So that if I am in a git bash shell, it will use `{Bash::Git bash}`; but if I am in a cmd prompt, it will use `{Shells::cmd}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this GUI Macro Command: `Shell("new_console")`
This will launch the same shell you have currently running.

[image: My Macro and its Shortcut]

I use it with the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: I don't think this will open a new shell in the same directory

Comment: You might have to play around with the %CD% a little bit.